# Binding data to a DropDownList Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap

I'm trying out a [sample example for SOAP demo in C#](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ooxn5QCHXCw). 
Unlike in the video, I'm trying out the same thing in an aspx file instead of windows forms.

*(PS: no need to watch the video)*

All in all, I'm trying to put a list of items of type `Currency` (imported via web references) in a `DropDownList` in aspx page.

I've created an aspx file and put a `WebControls.DropDownList` and a `button`.

`ComboBoxFrom` is the ID name of `DropDownList` in aspx page.

The following is my code on Page_Load method.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Currency> list = Enum.GetValues(typeof(Currency)).Cast<Currency>().ToList();
        ComboBoxFrom.DataSource = list;
        ComboBoxFrom.DataBind();
        ComboBoxFrom.Items.FindByValue(Convert.ToString(Currency.USD)).Selected = true;

    }
```

In my button click method I'm writing as

```
Currency curFrom = (Currency)ComboBoxFrom.SelectedItem;
```

Here, I get the error **Cannot convert type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' to 'SecureBillingService.net.webservicex.www.Currency'**

I understand that maybe since data in `ComboBoxFrom` might be binded during runtime maybe it's happening like this. **How to overcome this error ?**

I've tried to do like this

```
ComboBoxFrom.ItemType = Currency;
```

thinking that I'll force the compiler to assume the data type of items in the `ComboBoxFrom` as type of `Currency` but I get error that `Currency` is a type but is used like a variable.

**Edit**:

The code for the `Currency` class is not available. I'm getting this reference like the guy does in the video. From the Object Browser I see that it's declared as `public enum Currency` and it's base type is `Enum`. By the way i don't think it matters. Even if you create a custom class with a member variable then also it doesn't work. I finally tried to overcome this by creating a new dictionary with the key as `String` and value as `Currency`. Since `ComboBoxFrom.SelectedValue` gives `String`, I could work with that.

Btw the original question still stands. The problem here is that the compiler is not able to figure out that the list which I'm passing in `DropDownList` is not of `String` but of `Currency` type. (Maybe it's not even possible, but then the intellisense does not show this as error) So if I were to do `ComboBoxFrom.SelectedItem` then I expect to get an object of type `Currency`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The casting which you made in the button was incorrect, try this:

```
Currency curFrom = (Currency)Enum.Parse(typeof(Currency), ComboBoxFrom.SelectedValue);
```